# How to target mouse events to the deeper JComponents while it is targeted to a JComponent that has a mouse listener

Tags: java, swing, event-handling, awt, jcomponent

In Swing, mouse events are automatically targeted to the deepest component that has mouse listeners.
How to target them to the deeper components again while there is a component that has mouse listeners and is added on top of others?

It should be done without setting the component invisible or removing its mouse listeners because it is a transparent `JPanel` that should do some works depending on mouse events.

`dispatchEvent()` is useful only when the target component is known(i.e. the next deeper component).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> dispatchEvent() is useful only when the target component is known(i.e. the next deeper component).

You can use the `getParent()` method to get the next deeper comoponent.

You can also use the `SwingUtillities.getAncestorOfClass(...)` to find a specific parent class.